# Should the Ember hbs template pass in parameters from an input field to a function and if so how?

Tags: ember.js

I have a form that has an input field and an associated button and I have a function that would like to have the value the user types into the input field. Should I be passing it somehow from the hbs template or should I just go and get it from the DOM in the function.

Is there something like this?

```
{{ action myFunction $("#myInputId").val() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually - you are on the right track.

In this case... here is a route (application route)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  alertInput: function(inputValue) {
    alert(inputValue);
  },

  actions: {
    doSomething(userInput) { // (this is already a function)
    // alert(userInput); // or... use a regular function in the action
      this.get('alertInput')(userInput);
    },
  },

});
```

and here is a template (application template)

```
{{input value=userInputProperty}}

<button {{action 'doSomething' userInputProperty}}>doSomething</button>
```

This action takes a function name - and then a value as a parameter to pass to the function.

There a few ways you might do things depending on what you are trying to do.

https://ember-twiddle.com/3080649ecf98cddef6d3d64b186ba741?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C
(good time for a twiddle)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this by `value` property of `action` as shown below:

```
<input oninput={{action "myaction" value="target.value"}}/>
```

Here is an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/caeedd55d90c528dc439bb0535054c4b?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) for you.

Comment: But I want a separate button that will send the value from a different input field. I think in this case the target.value applies to the same input right? (Sorry the question was vague)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the value of the input box to a controller property and you can use that property to derive the value of the input box in the button action.

Here is an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/25d8096104a17c816db44af25b76a080?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for you.

Note: Ember Controllers are **SINGLETONS**.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the value directly is not possible, but you can bind the value to a property. 
I would suggest to wrap the input in a component and bind the input value to a component property. 
Then you can pass the value as action parameter or access it directly in the action handler of the component. 
This solution avoids a singleton controller and the component could be possibly reused.

See also https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/templates/actions and https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/templates/input-helpers.